# How to add multiple Hover Tools without showing multiple icons in the toolbar?

Tags: python, bokeh

Following the example [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/16e87ed63ca1aecaa42e93293f32d936685dcd3e/sphinx/source/docs/user_guide/examples/categorical_bar_stacked_hover.py) I have added multiple tooltips to a stacked bar chart. I also want to have other tools available in the toolbar above the plot, but when multiple hover tools are created using the process in the example it creates multiple icons in the tool bar, leaving it looking messy like this:

[image: toolbar]

Is there a way to add multiple hover tools, and have the toolbar visible with other tools in it, but not duplicate the hover icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `toggleable` attribute to `False`. Check this example, where the hover tool button is hidden:

```
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, LassoSelectTool, PanTool
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, curdoc

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[5, 6, 7, 8]
))

p = figure(
    width=400,
    height=400,
    tools='')

p.scatter(
    x='x', y='y', source=source,
    fill_alpha=1.0, line_alpha=1.0, line_color="grey",
    size=6
)

pan = PanTool()
lasso = LassoSelectTool()

tooltips = '''
    <b>X: </b> @{x} <br>
    <b>Y: </b> @{y} <br>
'''
hover = HoverTool(
    toggleable=False,       # add this to all your hover tools
    mode='mouse',
    tooltips=tooltips,
)

tools = (
    pan, lasso, hover
)
p.add_tools(*tools)

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Well, and if you want to use only one button then you might use only one hover tool. The model [**`CustomJSHover`**](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.CustomJSHover) may be useful for you.

As a workaround you can also update the [**`renderers`**](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.HoverTool.renderers) attribute of each hover pressing some button or custom tool.

Comment: So simple, d'oh! Thanks