# How to change the content of some tool button tooltip in a plot toolbar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hover, tooltip, bokeh

I currently have two HoverTools for two different shapes in my plot, and in the Tool Panel, it's not possible to distinguish the HoverTool of booth shape.

There is any way to change the tool name from "Hover" to something else?

An other option is to hide booth tools from the Tool Panel, is it possible?

[image: Tool Title]

```
plot = figure(tools='pan,wheel_zoom,save', active_scroll = "wheel_zoom", x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None, output_backend="webgl", plot_width=1200, plot_height= 600, match_aspect=True )

plot.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[shape1], tooltips=[('title1',"text1")]))
plot.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[shape2], tooltips=[('title2',"text2")]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second question

> An other option is to hide booth tools from the Tool Panel, is it possible?

I have already answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310352/4891717):

> Just set the [**`toggleable`**](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.Inspection.toggleable) attribute to `False`. Check this example, where the hover tool button is hidden:

```
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, LassoSelectTool, PanTool
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, curdoc

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[5, 6, 7, 8]
))

p = figure(
    width=400,
    height=400,
    tools='')

p.scatter(
    x='x', y='y', source=source,
    fill_alpha=1.0, line_alpha=1.0, line_color="grey",
    size=6
)

pan = PanTool()
lasso = LassoSelectTool()

tooltips = '''
    <b>X: </b> @{x} <br>
    <b>Y: </b> @{y} <br>
'''
hover = HoverTool(
    toggleable=False,       # add this to all your hover tools
    mode='mouse',
    tooltips=tooltips,
)

tools = (
    pan, lasso, hover
)
p.add_tools(*tools)

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Comment: "toggleable=False" made all the difference. It worked perfectly. Thanks for your anwser!

Comment: OK @MiguelGonçalves you are welcome. If the answer was helpful please vote it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly name the tools like this:

```
tools=['pan', 'box_zoom', 'wheel_zoom', 'crosshair', 'reset', 'save']
plot = figure(tools=tools, active_scroll = "wheel_zoom", x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None, output_backend="webgl", plot_width=1200, plot_height= 600, match_aspect=True )

shape1 = plot.line([0,1],[2,3])
shape2 = plot.line([4,5],[6,7])

h1 = HoverTool(renderers=[shape1], tooltips=[('title1',"text1")])
h2 = HoverTool(renderers=[shape2], tooltips=[('title2',"text2")])

plot.add_tools(h1, h2)
```

Another note - if you put h1 and h2 in the initial list where you declare the tools, you will get a warning saying duplicate hover tools.  I haven't seen this warning to cause an issue though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was actually trying to change the "Hover" label (in the image attached). Since i have 2 hover buttons in the tool panel, I cannot distinguish which is the right button for each shape.

Comment: Gotcha.  I looked into this a bit more....the "Hover" label in the toolbar seems to be defined in the Bokeh JS.  You can download this in your output file by specifying output_file(filename, mode='inline').  If you search for "Hover" you will find a line that specifies "e.tool_name="Hover"".  I tried changing this to "Hover1" and changing it once changed both hover tool names to Hover1.  So I'm not sure what you're trying to do is currently possible, unless maybe you are really good with JS...